# How do I allocate memory for an object with a const member variable without initializing the const? (C++)

Tags: arrays, memory-management, constructor, constants

I am trying to allocate memory for an array of objects of class "Esticker". The class includes a const char type variable, and this is causing me problems because I want to allocate the array memory block first, then initialize the values of each object within.

I am trying to use `malloc()` to do this because I tried using `new` and it wants a default constructor, which I need to avoid because I want to NOT construct anything right away.

Here is the code I have currently:

```
class Esticker
{
public:
    const char color;
    char current_face;
    char influencing_face;

    // default constructor - only including this because I wanted to test something
    Esticker():color('z'){} // The letter 'z' was chosen arbitrarily
    
    // The main constructor I want to use
    // I have to give c special treatment because it is a const
    Esticker(char c, char cf, char i) : color(c)
    {
        current_face = cf;
        influencing_face = i;
    }
};

int main()
{
    // Allocate memory for an array of 24 "Esticker" objects
    Esticker *E_Stickers = (Esticker *)malloc(sizeof(Esticker)*24);

    // Initialize an "Esticker" object in the first slot of the array
    E_Stickers[0] = Esticker('a','a','a');
}
```

This is giving me the following error:

`function "Esticker::operator=(const Esticker &)" (declared implicitly) cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted functionC/C++(1776)`

I know for a fact that this same error also happens when I try to initialize an instance of "Esticker" (using the default constructor) and then assign values to it. As in when I try to do:

```
Esticker sticker1 = Esticker('a','a','a');

Esticker sticker2;
sticker2 = sticker1;
```

The last line will throw the same error 1776 as above.

Is there a way to get around this problem? Or should I rethink how I want to code this in the first place? For context I am pretty new to C++ and am currently trying to make a Rubik's cube program for my own practice.

Answer (score 0):

"I want to allocate the array memory block first, then initialize the values of each object within."
If you know the number of objects at compile time than you can use `std::vector( 24)`, if not than go for a regular `std::vector`. After you've created one of these, you can just append Esticker objects as you create them.

```
function "Esticker::operator=(const Esticker &)" (declared implicitly) cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted functionC/C++(1776)
```

Since you've written your own default constructor you shall right your own operator=. This is tricky because you have a `const` member. If you use an std::array, it would look like this:

int main()
{

```
std::vector<Esticker> eStickers(24); //preallocate the size

// Initialize an "Esticker" object in the first slot of the array
eStickers.emplace_back('a','a','a');
```

}